# GMail imap connection blocked because the server is in different country

Tags: php, email, connection, gmail, blocked

I have a web application developed in PHP that connects to GMail using PHP IMAP extension, this extension is enabled and working correctly. When I try to connect to GMail using IMAP in my application, on my local server it works correctly (I live in Brazil), but when I put the application in production server, located in USA the GMail servers blocks my connection attempt. Other e-mail providers such as Yahoo or Hotmail (Outlook) works fine, this error only occurs with GMail accounts. When I perform local tests, all is fine, when I test it in my production server, I cannot connect and I receive GMail messages talking about the blocked login attempt. I don't know how I solve this, I thought to use a proxy server but this can left the application very slow.

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Because Google is the only provider that seems to care if your account is compromised and being accessed from further away than you could possibly have travelled since your last login. See @slapyo's answer, the link for which should also be in the error message the server returned when you tried to log in.

Comment: I knew about this security rule of Google accounts, but the message returned by server when I try to log in has a link to the home page of Google account management, I will see @slapyo's link. Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you visited this URL yet? If not, go there and follow the instructions then try to sign in again with your application on the production server.

https://accounts.google.com/displayunlockcaptcha